# Rails mass create from array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get params like this: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "events"=>{"363"=>{"name"=>"3"}}, "new_events"=>[{"name"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"2"}], "date"=>"2016-11-01"}`
What I would like to do is create Events from new_events array of hashes, but it doesn's let me because it neets to be sanitized for mass assignment.
This is how event_params looks like:

```
 def event_params
  params.require(:events).permit(:id, :name, :start_time, :user_id)
end
```

This setup is because I want to update and/or create new records when I press submit. 
The current way I do this is

```
params[:new_events].each_with_object({}) do |e|
    Event.create(name: e[:name], user_id: current_user.id, start_time: params[:date])
end
```

But Im not sure it's the correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sanitize the array of parameters:

```
params.require(:events).permit(new_events: [:name])
Event.create(params[:new_events] do |new_event|
    new_event.user = current_user
end
```

But note that you'll have to loop over the objects anyway, so it doesn't make much of a difference. You may want to just do the loop with `Event.new` and validate them as a group:

```
events = Event.new(params[:new_events]) do |new_event|
    new_event.user = current_user
    ...
end

if events.any?(&:invalid?)
    [error handling]
else
    events.save!
```

Comment: new_events is not a member of events.

Comment: new_events is seperated from events hash, its an array with hashes. Im trying to create and update at the same time